# iOS load multiple view from viewcontroller and save them as image

Tags: ios, objective-c, image

I have a view controller which have 4 tabs(some tabs include scrollview with multiple views in it). I need to save all the contents of the tabs into 4 pictures. I managed to let each tab return me a `UIImage` for me to save. However i discovered a problem, if i didn't tap on the tab bar (which is to say didn't manually load them and show them on screen), the tabs can't return me an Image because there is no view for them to take reference to. So my question is, do I preload the tabs-view? If so, how?
If not preload, is there a better workaround?

Part of my codes:

View Controller use this to share:

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[shareText,[_summaryViewController getImageToShare],[_sessionLogViewController getImageToShare] ,[_breakdownViewController getImageToShare],[_skillsViewController getImageToShare]] applicationActivities:nil];
```

`getImageToShare`:

```
-(UIImage*) getImageToShare
{
    UIImage *image = nil;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollView.contentSize, NO, 0.0);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffSet = self.scrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = self.scrollView.frame;

        self.scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        self.scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.scrollView.contentSize.width, self.scrollView.contentSize.height);
        [self.scrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = [ViewToImage ImageWithView:self.scrollView];

        self.scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffSet;
        self.scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    if (image != nil) {
        NSLog(@"there is something returned:%@",image);
    }else
        NSLog(@"nothign is returned");

    return image;
}
```

Comment: you mean you want to show 4 different images in all tab may i correct.

Comment: Hi yes, I want to show 4 different images, rather save them. Its like a summay page, I managed to let the functions return me correct contents In Image i would like to save. The only problem is, if i didn't press on the tab to show(load) the pages, it would return nil. Should i change my ViewToImage? Should i upload it here for more information?

Comment: Okay nvm, after further digging, I have realised u can call [_viewcontroller view] to preload the view. Now one problem arise. I have some animation on the 4 tabs, if i do the preload method, the picture return is before the animation finish. I can't see the data i want.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out, I just need to create copy of the tabs and then make them don't animate and just show the data. Then preload them and use their Image instead.